# Cross Table JOIN error

Tags: mysql, join

I unfortunately don't know what the issue is though?

```
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_varchar SET value = '{somevalue}'

    FROM cataloginventory_stock_item AS csi
    JOIN catalog_product_entity AS cpe ON cpe.entity_id = csi.product_id
    JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar AS cpev ON cpev.entity_id = cpe.entity_id

WHERE attribute_id = '1691' AND sku = '605284470695';
```

**ERROR**

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM cataloginventory_stock_item AS csi      JOIN catalog_pr' at line 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SET` clause should come after the table references:

```
UPDATE
  cataloginventory_stock_item AS csi
  JOIN catalog_product_entity AS cpe ON cpe.entity_id = csi.product_id
  JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar AS cpev ON cpev.entity_id = cpe.entity_id
SET cpev.value = '{somevalue}'
WHERE attribute_id = '1691' AND sku = '605284470695';
```

Comment: `Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM smartwool.cataloginventory_stock_item AS csi    JOIN smartwool.catalog_prod' at line 2`

Comment: Forgive me, the `FROM` keyword shouldn't be there at all.  I have removed it from my answer.

Comment: Almost, I get an unknown `Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'catalog_product_entity_varchar.value' in 'field list'`

Comment: `value` is the name of the column

Comment: Silly me: the table is aliased `cpev`!  I have updated my answer.

Comment: That was it, great coding eggypal

Answer (score 0):

you can't do `UPDATE ... FROM`. That's utterly invalid syntax. Perhaps you're thinking of `INSERT INTO ... SELECT FROM`?

Comment: I think the OP wants to do a [multi-table `UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html).

Comment: @MikePurcell: It's only one keyword (`FROM`) that makes the OP's syntax "utterly invalid"; other than that the only error was the order in which the clauses appeared.  A suggestion of how to fix the statement to what the OP had intended would have been infinitely more useful than a pointer towards `INSERT ... SELECT`?!